# How to block China Telecom Zhejiang ip range

Tags: centos

in last week i have heavy SSH login attack form China Telecom Zhejiang.
i have the range ip : 122.224.216.0 - 122.225.191.255 But i don't know how to block ip range like that in Firewall - csf v7.56.?! I use centos6 and  Firewall - csf v7.56.
please if possible help me thank you.

Answer (score 4):

To block IP Ranges using Config Server Firewall use:

```
csf -d 122.224.216.0/21
csf -d 122.224.224.0/19
csf -d 122.225.0.0/17
csf -d 122.225.128.0/18
```

If you wish to block any further IP (Range) then I recommend you look into this tool:
http://ip2cidr.com/

---

Going into further detail, If you wish to protect your server from Brute Force SSH Attacks, you can use the following methods:

1- If you will always be connecting to your server from the same IP address, you can firewall off port 22 to everything EXCEPT your own IP address.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s YOUR.IP.GOES.HERE --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 22 -j DROP
```

Then run `'iptables-save'`

**Note**: if you setup IP tables this way then it may cause you to lose ssh access to your server if your IP ever changes.

2- Run sshd on a non-standard port. Since most automated attacks only attempt to connect on port 22, this can be an effective way to hide from automated attackers. To configure this, just change the Port line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and restart ssh

Port 1022

3- Use the AllowUsers directive in the ssh configuration to only allow certain users or IP's. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, you can specify a list of allowed users like this:

```
AllowUsers bob john root@11.22.33.44 root@99.88.77.66
```

This will allow users 'bob' and 'john' to log in from anywhere, and root is only allowed to log in from those two IP addresses.

4- Use strong passwords! Brute force attempts will try common passwords like words (or combinations of words) in a dictionary, names, and common passwords. Strong passwords generally use a combination of upper and lower-case characters, numbers, and non-alphanumeric characters.

5- Even better, don't use passwords at all. Instead, install your public key on the server and use it to log in. If all of your users will use public keys, you can set PasswordAuthentication to 'no'. To disable password authentication just for root, use 'PermitRootLogin without-password'. For Debian/Ubuntu, you'll also need to turn off 'UsePam' and 'ChallengeResponseAuthentication'.

6- If you need to permit logins from arbitrary addresses, consider using a program like DenyHosts or Fail2ban. They watch for failed logins and add the IP addresses of attackers to /etc/hosts.deny and/or update firewall rules to null route them. DenyHosts can also be configured to synchronize with a global database so you can proactively deny hosts that other users have blacklisted.  Keep in mind that mistyping your password when you try to log in will then probably lock you out of your VPS.

7- Use 'hashlimit' in 'iptables':

```
iptables -I INPUT -m hashlimit -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 --hashlimit 1/min 
--hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name ssh -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

This rule limits one connection to the SSH port from one IP address per minute.

For more information, 'man iptables' and 'iptables -m hashlimit --help'.

(Information from: http://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/misc/preventing-brute-force-ssh-attacks)

Comment: In addition to your excellent answer (+1) : when changing the port SSHD listens on in CentOS you'll also need to enable the new port in SELinux: `semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 1022`